# pyparsing parse nested expression with multiple opener and closer

Tags: python, context-free-grammar, pyparsing

Basically I want to parse the string with nested brackets/parantheses.

```
opening = oneOf("( { [")
closing = oneOf(") } ]")
scanner = originalTextFor(nestedExpr(opening, closing))

data = 'a b c [(xx), (yyy) zz)'
```

However, firstly,  it gives me

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-f6f023bf4229> in <module>
      1 opening = oneOf("( { [")
      2 closing = oneOf(") } ]")
----> 3 scanner = originalTextFor(nestedExpr(opening, closing))

/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in nestedExpr(opener, closer, content, ignoreExpr)
   6201                                        ).setParseAction(lambda t: t[0].strip()))
   6202         else:
-> 6203             raise ValueError("opening and closing arguments must be strings if no content expression is given")
   6204     ret = Forward()
   6205     if ignoreExpr is not None:

ValueError: opening and closing arguments must be strings if no content expression is given
```

Secondly,  I am trying to get the nested structure(list) as output like this:

```
[['xx'], ',', ['yyy'], 'zz']
```

But I get a whole string instead of a nested structure.

Comment: [Please show](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146) the *complete* error message.

Comment: The error message indicates that, if you don't specify strings for the opener and closer, then you have to specify a content argument also. With this example, try adding `content=Word(alphas)`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel updated